# Emitting events from an observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to create an observable that will make a connection with a stream through a websocket then emit those events.

here is a basic example of how I'd like to model it:

```
const observable = defer(() => connectToWs()).pipe(
   tap(wsClient => {
      wsClient.subscribe('channel')

      wsClient.messageReceived = (msg) => {
         // emit msg here
      }
   }
)
```

But I'm a bit stuck on how to emit the `msg` variable after using a creation operator like `defer`, any help or advice with rxjs would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can to create an `observable` inside `switchMap` for message to be emitted.

```
const observable = defer(() => connectToWs()).pipe(
   tap(wsClient =>wsClient.subscribe('channel'))
   switchMap(wsClient=>{
      return new Observable(obs=>{
        wsClient.messageReceived = (msg) => {
          obs.next(msg) 
      }
    }
   }
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than manipulating your client objects within an observable subscription, I suggest encapsulating the client subscribe/unsubscribe logic by writing a function with the signature:

`(client: WsClient) => Observable<Message>`

(I'm making up the types here, but hopefully you get the idea.)

```
const observeChannel = (
  client: WsClient,
  channel: string
): Observable<Message> => {
  return new Observable<Message>((observer) => {
    client.subscribe("channel");

    client.messageReceived = (msg: Message) => {
      observer.next(msg);
    };
    return () => {
      // unsubscribe logic
    };
  });
};

const observable = defer(() => connectToWs()).pipe(
  switchMap((client) => observeChannel(client, "channel"))
);
```